# Problem about dual of $W = V \oplus V'$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $V$ by finite dimensional, let $W = V \oplus V'$, and prove that the correspondence $(x,y) \rightarrow (y,x)$ is an isomorphism between $W$ and $W'$. (The direct sum is defined as the set of all ordered pairs of the summands).

I don't know how to approach proving injectivity. To prove surjectivity, I'd need some idea of what the elements of $W'$ even are.

They are linear functionals on $V \oplus V'$ I suppose. The problem suggests they are of the form $(y,x)$. But how could $(y,x)$ act as a scalar-valued function on $(x,y)$? Does the action of $(y,x)$ on $(x,y)$ simply return $y(x)$?

I don't know how to approach this problem in general. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is $V^\prime$? The dual space of $V$?

Comment: $W'\simeq V'\oplus W''$, and, as $V$  is finite dimensional, $\;V\simeq V''$.

Comment: Sorry, yes, $V'$ is the dual space of $V$. And @Bernard could you elaborate?

Comment: @agrasin: Yes, but only tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that if $V$, $W$ are two vector space, then one has

$$ \varphi: V' \oplus W' \longrightarrow (V\oplus W)'\\
(f,g) \longmapsto \begin{array}{@{} l c @{}} V \oplus W  &\longrightarrow &K \\ (x,y) & \longmapsto &f(x)g(y) \end{array}
$$

Can you prove that $\varphi$ is injective. After that, you can prove that if $V$ and $W$ are finite dimensional, then $\varphi$ is surjective, so are bijective.

Now, come back to your problem, one has that $$V'\oplus V'' \simeq (V\oplus V')' = W'$$.

Note that
$$V'\oplus V'' \simeq V'\oplus V$$

Now, one can see $$V'\oplus V \simeq V \oplus V'$$ with the map $(x,y) \longmapsto (y,x)$.